# omnet++ inet multi destination for udp packet (ini file)

Tags: ini, omnet++, inet

my network is a mesh one. i want to send data from hostA* to hostB* .
a range is 3 (hostA0, hostA1,  hostA2, hostA3), destination hosts are (hostB0, hostB1). 
(hosts are in inet.node.inet.INetworkNode type).

how i set this property with wild card in scenario .ini file?
i try with

```
*.hostA*.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "hostB*"
*.hostA*.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "hostB0, hostB1"
*.hostA*.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "hostB0 hostB1"
*.hostA*.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "hostB${0,1}"
```

but they don't work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use wildcard inside a string constant. Wildcards can be used only in the keys. The reason is that wildcards are not expanded like they are on a shell command line. Instead they work in a way that whenever you read in a parameter in omnet, it scans the INI file and returns the first matching parameter defined (taking into account the wildcard). So its rather matching the parameters instead of expanding them.

According the the docs of BasicUDPApp the space separated one (third one) should be used.